# Boto3: How can I set Security Group Ids to default?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to set security group ids while creating an EC2 instance. If I have a specific security group Id list, I can do this:

```
        boto3.resource(resource, region_name=self.region)
        ec2 = self.resource

        instances = ec2.create_instances(
             ImageId=image_id,
             MinCount=minCount,
             MaxCount=maxCount,
             InstanceType=instance_type,
             SubnetId=subnet_id,
             KeyName=key_pair,               
             SecurityGroupIds=security_groups
         )
```

If I don't have the security group ids I'd like to use a default security group ids that get associated to `launch-wizard-#` security group if I don't pass `SecurityGroupIds` argument in `ec2.create_instances`. Is there a way to pass something to `SecurityGroupIds` argument that tells  boto3 to use default security group Id? More specifically:

```
        instances = ec2.create_instances(
             ImageId=image_id,
             MinCount=minCount,
             MaxCount=maxCount,
             InstanceType=instance_type,
             SubnetId=subnet_id,
             KeyName=key_pair,               
             SecurityGroupIds= <"What do I pass here so that boto3 takes in defaults?">
         )
```

So that I get the same behavior as below (using the previous code snippet):

```
    instances = ec2.create_instances(
         ImageId=image_id,
         MinCount=minCount,
         MaxCount=maxCount,
         InstanceType=instance_type,
         SubnetId=subnet_id,
         KeyName=key_pair,               
     )
```

Comment: Hi @kirtiman-sinha, your question would have a better chance to be answered on server fault. My 2 cents.

Comment: Got it. I'll also add it there. I put it here since stack overflow has many more watchers for these tags than Server Fault.

Comment: If `None` doesn't work, then you will probaby need to build the args in a dict and then pass via `ec2.create_instances(**yourargs)`

Comment: I get that but I was wondering if there was a "default" value